# Burn [rectangle] related tags

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135985/clean-up-of-run-together-hyphenated-and-singular-plural-tags/135994#135994) [rectangle](/questions/tagged/rectangle) once had over 400 questions and now there are none. It looks like the tag was burninated at some point. Can we also burn the equally useless [rect](/questions/tagged/rect) and [rectangles](/questions/tagged/rectangles)?

Answer (score 5):

Hmm... Two down-votes so far and no commentary, so I'll toss my opinion in on the off-chance that folks agree/disagree.

I don't feel strongly about [rectangles](/questions/tagged/rectangles) - yes, the non-plural version was removed, but so far as I can tell it's *usually* actually used to refer to... well... quadrilateral shapes with four right angles.

[rect](/questions/tagged/rect) is a bit more problematic, since it's the name of a data type on many platforms. Which would be fine, except there are a *lot* of different structures with the exact same name - oh, and it also seems to be used to refer to [rectangles](/questions/tagged/rectangles) in some cases, and [in one case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227752/how-to-get-mouse-x-y-position-in-a-specified-area-of-window-winapi) was used by someone determined to put spaces in an API function name.

I recommend leaving [rectangles](/questions/tagged/rectangles) and removing [rect](/questions/tagged/rect).

Comment: I've posted a suggested edit for the `rect` tag if you'd like to review it. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rect/info